# Простой рабочий пример общения json, ajax, php

Tags: json, php, ajax

Подскажите простой рабочий пример общения этих сущностей (json (файл) ajax php).

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs 
jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).keyup(function(){
    $.ajax({
url:'json.php',
type:'POST',
data:{'data':JSON.stringify(["Яблоко", "Апельсин", "Слива"])}
});
</script>
<form action=""><input type="search" id="search-text"> <input type="submit"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

php

```
var_dump(json_decode($_POST['data']));
```

В чём ошибка? Как сюда добавить файл?

Comment: Какой файл сюда надо добавить?  Какая ошибка? Что ругается: JS или PHP?

Для того, чтобы получить ответ на вопрос, надо предоставить все данные по этому вопросу..  Плюс к тому: сначала надо погуглить - таких примеров вагон и маленькая тележка

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['data'])) {
    var_dump(json_decode($_POST['data']));

    die();
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'index.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{'data':JSON.stringify(["Яблоко", "Апельсин", "Слива"])}
    });
});
</script>
<form action=""><input type="search" id="search-text"> <input type="submit"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: нет, не работает

Comment: Вам может быть еще и веб-сервер настроить, рабочую машину в ДЦ подключить?

Comment: нет, это все работает. сейчас я отредактирую вопрос с вашим премером

Comment: без var_dump() только просто echo json_decode($_POST['data'])

Comment: @ferz это пример, но не сказано, что он должен быть рабочим. А не работать он может по нескольким причинам. Либо вы не догадались запихнуть массив в JSON.stringify(array), либо не подключили jQuery, либо у вас php не работает, либо точку с запятой потеряли, либо etc...

Comment: @ferz обновил пост.

Comment: Если мне кто-нибудь объяснит, нафига тут JSON.stringify, я буду просто счастлив

Comment: @Photon на пальцах: как я понял, у человека файл с текстом в json формате. Я же вместо файла преобразую массив в json формат при помощи JSON.stringify. А вообще в начале про файл ничего сказано не было. Вот и думай, что ТС имел ввиду.

Comment: наверное вопрос следует перезадать?

Answer (score 5):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/ajax/order",
   data: {id:'123123'}
   success: function(html){
       var res = JSON.parse(html);
       alert(html); // просто вывод ответа
       alert(res); // распарсим JSON
    }
 });
```

**/ajax/order.php**

```
$options=array(
"status"=>1,
"err"=>$_POST['id'],
 );
echo json_encode($options);
```

Comment: отправляйте функцией аякс данные так:  

    data: "id=123123",

тогда $\_POST['id'] получит 123123  
а вот отправляя что либо из пхп в обратку к жаваскрипту можно использовать json\_encode(sometings), тогда переменная html из  

    success: function(html){
  
подучит значение уже в виде объекта (если это нужно)

Comment: я чего-то не понимаю или это плагиат на мой ответ?

Comment: Кстати, чтоб не делать JSON.parse(), можно просто сделать так:

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        ....
    });

И тогда в функцию success придёт сразу готовый массив

Comment: Можно. Никто не запрещает :)

Comment: Почему плагиат? Объяснение.