# Ajax отправка и получения ответа

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Хотел узнать у тех кто разбирается, правильно ли я делаю, потому как мне кажется, что я изобретаю велосипед.
С помощью jQuery я отправляю на сервер переменную, затем в php эта переменная обрабатывается функцией и выводиться `echo "$login";` После этого в javascript в переменную `data` передается переменная `login` со всей html страницей. После чего мне приходиться отделять эту переменную от страницы и затем сравнивать. Мне кажется что это не совсем надежно и я где-то ошибся. Есть ли другие способы получения ответа без html-страницы? Заранее спасибо за помощь. Код предоставлен ниже.

```
$.ajax({
    method : "POST",
    url : "",
    dataType : "text",
    success : function (data) {
        // Получаем ответ с сервера с помощью ajax
        data = explode(" ", data);
        if (data[0] != "<!DOCTYPE") {
            location.reload();
        }
    },
    data : {
        "check" : true
    }
});
```

PHP-код:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $result3 = $this->room1_model->checkParty($login);
    if ($result3) {
        echo $result3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Используйте при передачи формат обмена данными JSON и передавайте не всю страницу, а только нужные переменные. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/164060/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-json-ajax-php#164066

Comment: Тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430240/%D0%92%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C-ajax-%D1%81-php/430248#430248 лучше пример.

Comment: Не страницц а блок лучше возвращать и каждый раз его обновлять. Хотя все зависит от конкретной задачи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой пример:

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/test.php',
    data: 'string=1234',
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.result == "yes") {
            alert("YES");
        } else {
            alert("NO");
        }
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['string'])) {

    $my_string = trim($_POST['string']);
    $my_string = strip_tags($my_string);
    $my_string = stripslashes($my_string);
    $my_string = htmlspecialchars($my_string, ENT_QUOTES);

    if($my_string == "1234") {
        echo json_encode(array('result' => 'yes'));
        return;
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('result' => 'no'));
        return; 
    }

} else {
    exit;
}
?>
```